# why my Function isn't giving the required output

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that generates all two-character combinations of the alphabet from 'a' to 'z', and if the permutations include both 'x' and 'z', print them and break

```
import itertools
def gen2(n):
 alplist = list(map(chr,list(range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1))))
 for combi in itertools.product(alplist,*([alplist] * 2)):
   return gen2(2)
   if "x" and "z" in combi:
    print(combi)
    break
```

But I'm not getting an output what can be the problem?

Comment: You have a `return` before the `if` so you will never reach that `if`. By the way, your almost unreadable `list(map ...` can be replaced by `string.ascii_lowercase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has five issues:

1. `return gen2(2)` inside the main `for-loop` prevents the execution of the code. Also this freezes the code, since the recursive calls are nested indefinitely.
2. `if "x" and "z" in combi:` does not work properly. Python will interpret this as only `if "z" in combi:` because `"x"` is always defined as a non-empty variable, and thus `"x"` is evaluated as `True`. You need to write `if "x" in combi and  "z" in combi:`
3. In `def gen2(n):`, the input parameter `n` can be removed  because it is not used inside the code. You can write `def gen2():`
4. The issue with the length of the string is caused by `itertools.product(alplist,*([alplist] * 2))`. If you want 2 characters, you need to write `itertools.product(alplist, repeat = 2)`. (credits to @John Coleman for the improved syntax)
5. `list(map(chr,list(range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1))))` is the same as `string.ascii_lowercase`. (credits to @John Coleman)

The corrected code is:

```
import itertools
import string
def gen2():
    for combi in itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat = 2):
        if "x" in combi and  "z" in combi:
            print(combi)
            break
gen2()
```

Comment: n is supposed to be 2 which represents the number of characters in each combination

Comment: Actually `n` is not really necessary, it is never used by the code.

Comment: The code works properly, I tested it on my console.

Comment: But I'm getting 3 characters instead of 2

Comment: I fixed the length of the string. See my updated point 4.

Comment: `itertools.product(alplist, repeat = 2)` would be more idiomatic than `itertools.product(alplist,*[alplist])`

Comment: Thanks, yes that sounds a lot better. I never use `itertools`, so I am not very familiar with the library.

Comment: I would gladly upvote this answer if you fix OP's 47-symbols, 7 function calls monstrosity for obtaining the 26 lower case ascii letters. That code is somewhat absurd and I don't think it should be retained in an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the construction of `string.ascii_lowercase`.